# How to view thymeleaf templates without running the server

Tags: java, spring, view, thymeleaf

I haven't found an answer with would satify me - I found only Thymol which does not work or seem not to be supported anymore.

Is there any way to view the thymeleaf templates via browser without having to run the server like it is with "normal" htmls views with append css files? If not, then do you know any good practices or methods on how to see realtime in React (or, if not realtime, then not running the whole app at least) what you are editing?

Comment: drag and drop it on your browser.  It's just HTML.  Make sure you have the path CSS referenced properly

Comment: if that's not clear, can you post some sample code to what you're referencing?

Answer (score 1):

Add to the application.propreties file: 
`spring.thymeleaf.cache=false`

Run the app in Debug mode

Than, when you change some file, just rebuild that file (in intellij it should be the shortcut Ctrl+F9).

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed a little faster

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Spring, you can use Spring DevTools to achieve that. Just add a proper dependency to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you just edit your template file, save it and refresh the page in your browser. No rebuild is needed.

Above will indeed require to run the app/server, but only once. I think that was worth to post it here anyway.